# demandware site updates not instant

Tags: caching, server, updates, demandware

My company has recently begun using demandware, however we are finding it slightly odd that instant site updates are not possible, whether through a cache clear or server updates, at the moment our servers update every 24 hours, so effectively any changes we make one day won't go live until the following day. In demandware is there anything that can be done so we can instantly see new updates to our site or perhaps a server update occurring every hour?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is that change that you want to be instant as update on production?

Why it should be instant, even if the site is over heavy load at the moment?

There are various ways you can achieve quicker updates (remote includes with different caching, integration feeds targeted on production, cache segmentation, etc.), still I need more details about what exactly you are trying to do to suggest you appropriate solution.

Also your question is better suited in [Demandware XChange portal](https://xchange.demandware.com), not in Stack Overflow, as this is site for programming, and your question is not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make instant changes on Demandware. you can however makes changes that will be reflected on the site within 15 mintues. To do this, you will need to be logged in to production.

There are typically three instances that you can make changes; development, staging and production. If you are seeing the changes come through after 24 hours then you are most certainly logged in to the staging instance, where changes are replicated over to production at a designated time.

What you'll need to do is login to production and make the required update. Then, clear your site cache to make the change visible on the live site. You will then need to wait on average 15 minutes for the data centres to dump their cache and serve a new copy of the site.

To clear the site cache:

1) Navigate to Administration > Manage Sites

2) Select the relevant brand/region

3) Click the Cache tab

4) Click the first "Invalidate" button

Answer (score 0):

For clearing cache.. 
You need to go to Administration -> Manage Sites -> Select the site -> Click Cache tab and then click on Invalidate Cache.
..
This initialises the cache invalidation process which usually takes some time but not an entire day.
..
Please check if there are any other caching mechanisms added for your sites.
Usually, Invalidating cache works just fine.